# IntelliJ(Cursive): Navigate between the code window and the REPL window

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, keymapping, cursive

I'm looking for a keymap that enables me to jump between the window of the source code to the window of REPL. Do you know how this keymap is named in Keymap tab in Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

cmd+1 opens the project tool window.

I use cmd+3 to open the repl tool window.

You have to set the order of your tool windows such that REPL is 3rd to do this.